# Button on click declared in js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to create a new `p` tag after the `button` is clicked yet nothing happens after it's clicked:

```
(function() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 403) {
      var heading = document.getElementById("head");
      var para = document.createElement("P");
      para.innerHTML = "Accept the T&Cs to Continue";
      var button = document.createElement("BUTTON"); // button created here
      button.classList.add("theButton");
      var theButton = document.getElementsByClassName("theButton");
      theButton.onclick = function() { // button doesn't work onclick
        var newP = document.createElement("P");
        newP.innerHTML = "DONE";
        heading.appendChild(newP);
        heading.appendChild(para);
        heading.appendChild(button);
      };
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/content.ajax", true);
  xhttp.send();
})();
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: you create it but you never insert it to the DOM. Or am I missing something?

Comment: For some reason, the code to append the button to the DOM is within the click event handler. That doesn't do much good. Move the line `heading.appendChild(button)` out of that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m assuming that document.getElementsByClassName("theButton") should get your button, because it uses the same class.

1. That´s unnecessary because you already have a reference to your button.
2. Your button (and para) did not get attached to the DOM, so getElementsByClassName would return an empty result.
3. document.getElementsByClassName() returns a HTMLCollection (a list), not a single element. You can´t add a listener function to a HTMLCollection.
4. The button only gets added to the DOM when it is clicked. But you can only click it after it got added to the DOM.

Also you should consider using addEventListener because your listener can´t be overwritten that way and you can add multiple listeners.

```
(function () {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState ==4 && this.status == 403){
            var heading = document.getElementById("head");
            var para = document.createElement("P");
            para.innerHTML = "Accept the T&Cs to Continue";

            var button = document.createElement("BUTTON"); // button created here
            button.classList.add("theButton");
            button.addEventListener("click", function() {
                var newP = document.createElement("P");
                newP.innerHTML = "DONE";
                heading.appendChild(newP);
            });

            heading.appendChild(para);
            heading.appendChild(button);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET","/content.ajax",true);
    xhttp.send();
})();
```

Comment: Understood! Thank you!